# Is it possible to create a custom MSMessageLayout for iMessage app extension? If so, can some one provide me an example

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage-extension, msmessage, msmessagetemplatelayout

Among the examples I have seen so far for iMessage-App extensions, I learned that the only way to send GIF is through creating a `MSSticker` and attaching a gif to it for sending. But, after observing some apps. I saw that **GIPHY** sends GIF through `MSMessageTemplateLayout` or `MSMessageLayout`. I know this because of how `MSSticker` and `MSMessageLayout` looks on the screen. You can see that in the images below:

[image: This gif is <code>MSSticker</code>]

This above image is gif inserted through `MSSticker`.

[image: This gif is <code>MSMessageLayout</code>]

This above image is gif inserted through `MSMessageLayout`.

The problem here is `MSMessageLayout` doesn't have any method to override. There is no way that I know by which we can insert gif into `MSMessageTemplateLayout` and make it play. I tried it. The only way I know is to create a custom `MSMessageLayout` which I don't find any examples for.

The major reason for me trying this method is:

- There is 500 kb limit for size of GIF we can send through `MSSticker`
- Through GIPHY, we can send a GIF with size greater than 500 kb. I checked it myself

So, two humble requests to the community:

- If anyone already tried sending GIF through `MSMessageLayout`, please answer how you did it
- If anyone succeded in sending GIF of size > 500 kb through `MSSticker`, please answer how you did it

Comment: Not sure if it works with GIFs, but have you tried to call the `insertAttachment(_:)` method? Since it's actually missing the app logo on the top-left corner, this cannot be an `MSMessageTemplateLayout` message

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti, I haven't tried it. Let me check

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti, it's working. Thanks man. Please write it as an answer :)

Comment: done :) Happy that it helped you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you send a `MSMessage` inside a `MSMessageTemplateLayout`, the app icon is shown on the top-left corner (in your screenshot, it doesn't appear) so this makes me think that they probably use `insertAttachment(_:)`. In this way the media is handled automatically by iMessage as it has been sent via sharing from any other apps.